# Why didn't Sherock let Watson in on his Empty Hearse plot?

Tags: plot-explanation, sherlock

Why does Sherlock keep his fake death to John if 30 other people know about his fake death. Wouldn't you think if it is a secret, John would be the first person he could trust about this secret? I don't understand the purpose of setting the "stage" just for John, if it is also for other onlookers.

(Although I'm not entirely sure if the last explanation is the real explanation for his fake death, I'm just leaving it as a plot the directors can't really solve so they just made it vague as possible.)

Comment: or did they just do it would parallel with the "Final Problem"

Comment: The "stage" wasn't setup up just for john, it was for the snipers as well.

Answer (score 3):

Because they had to convince the world that Sherlock was dead. What better way to do that than convince Watson? If Watson appeared in front of the world honestly grief stricken, then the world would more easily believe that Sherlock was dead.